# Proxy環境下でのElectron開発について

Tags: google-chrome, electron

Proxy環境下でVue.js + ElectronでVue.jsのサンプルを実行しようとしたのですが、Vue.jsをCNDで指定すると接続エラーが発生します。
Htmlファイルを直接開くと問題なく実行できるため、ElectronのChromiumにProxyを設定する必要があると思うのですが、Proxyの設定方法が分からず困っております。

[Supported Chrome command line switches](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.33.0/api/chrome-command-line-switches/)

上記サイトを参考に以下の通り設定しましたが**net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED**となり駄目でした。

```
'use strict';

// アプリケーションをコントロールするモジュール
var app = require('app');
//Chrome command line switches
//app.commandLine.appendSwitch('proxy-pac-url', '<PAC Url>');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('proxy-server', '<Prosy>:<Port>');
```

おそらく認証情報（ID,PASS）を設定していない為だと思うのですが、
認証ダイアログ等も表示されない為、別に設定する方法があれば教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 3):

2点あります。

## electron の wapper

以下の様な wrapper を書いておけばコードを弄る必要はないです。

```
electron . --proxy-server=proxy-server:port
```

## 認証を必要としない proxy-server を用意する

もし golang をビルド出来る環境があれば以下をビルドして実行しておくと良いです。

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "github.com/elazarl/goproxy"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    verbose := flag.Bool("v", false, "should every proxy request be logged to stdout")
    addr := flag.String("addr", ":8080", "proxy listen address")
    flag.Parse()
    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.Verbose = *verbose
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, proxy))
}
```

golang の http client は

```
http_proxy=http://USER:PASSWORD@proxy-server:port
```

という環境変数を認識するので

```
electron => local-proxy(認証なし) => actual-proxy(認証あり) => internet
```

という経路を辿って electron からは認証無しでネットワークに接続できる様になります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
また、お礼が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。
ご提示いただいた2点にて解決しました。
ありがとうございました。